# Tensor too big for graph distribution - "InternalError: Message length was negative"

Tags: python, tensorflow, distribution

**I tried to run the following graph:**
[image: Graph that causes the error.]

**Unfortunately, I receive the following error message:**

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InternalError: Message length was negativ
 [[Node: random_uniform_1_S1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false,
  recv_device= "/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0",
  send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
  send_device_incarnation=3959744268201087672,
  tensor_name="edge_18_random_uniform_1",
  tensor_type=DT_DOUBLE,
  _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I noticed that this error message does not occur if the size of `random_uniform_1` is 800MB, but it does occur if the size is 8GB.

(Notice that `random_uniform_1` has to be transferred from one device to another device.)

**Question:** Is there a limit on how big a tensor can be, if that tensor has to be transferred between devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, currently there is a **2GB limit** on an individual tensor when sending it between processes. This limit is imposed by the protocol buffer representation (more precisely, by the auto-generated C++ wrappers produced by the `protoc` compiler) that is used in TensorFlow's communication layer.

We are investigating ways to lift this restriction. In the mean time, you can work around it by manually adding `tf.split()` or `tf.slice()`, and `tf.concat()` operations to partition the tensor for transfer. If you have very large `tf.Variable` objects, you can use [variable partitioners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable-partitioners-for-sharding) to perform this transformation automatically. Note that in your program you have multiple 8GB tensors in memory at once, so the peak memory utilization will be at least 16GB.